# Music videos on topic?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope

Are questions about music videos on-topic?

I can easily see the FAQ being adapted to include music videos:

- Analysis of content or theme of all forms of Music videos
- Identifying a Music video
- Questions about a Music video's production.
- The works of a director / an actor / a writer related to Music video

But I could also see these questions being deferred to the [Music](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17796/music) proposal (if they want 'em).

Comment: As a note for anyone reading this question, keep in mind that downvotes mean **disagreement** when it comes to Meta and your *reputation* is not affected in anyway.

Comment: Indeed... as @TylerShads said... please don't hesitate to down-vote my question if you think music videos should not be on topic here.

Answer (score 9):

My gut reaction says meh.  The issue as I see it is, when does it stop being a question about the video and being a question about the music?

***As a movie/tv person I would not appreciate seeing questions about Lady Gaga's newest music video.***

Comment: +1.  My immediate reaction is the same - I'd be interested in hearing an opposing view though.

Comment: Yeah my initial reaction turned to Gaga beiber and the other patron saints of hell.  A counter-argument could be made about the filmography and such but I don't think it'll hold up very well.

Comment: I could try to form a counter-argument, but I don't really feel strongly about this. :)  I think a music site would probably be a better place for most music-video questions (possible exceptions might be questions specifically about directors/performers who cross genres into movies/TV)

Comment: I understand your reaction, and you don't want an army of teenagers to spam this stackexchange site... But there are a lot of interesting facts about old music videos that are focused on video itself, not the music. And something tells me, people who watch newest Lady Gaga music videos are not into stackexchange world...

Answer (score 4):

Due to the responses of the question by downvotes and the upvotes on the answer that says *get rid of them*

I am going to go out on a limb and say [identify-this-music-video](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-music-video) will be declared

### **Off-Topic**

For this site.